# Keep value "true" for disabled element in Vuejs

Tags: input, vue.js, disabled-input

I had one line code:

```
<input :disabled="isDisable">
```

and isDisable is return true or false. But when it render to DOM, it render

```
<input disabled="disabled">
```

In Chrome, it can disable an input. However, in Firefox, it disable, but I can type something in input. In fireFox, it only disable if disabled="true" not disabled="disabled".
HOw can I keep disabled="true" instead "disabled".
P/s: isDisable only have value true or false.
Thanks

Comment: I think you want `<input :disabled="isDisable">`

Comment: Sorry, I mistook my code. I edited my code in question. But it still error.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere? Because that line doesn't seem to have a problem.

Comment: I have type="number" and I don't know does it cause problem. When I remove tpe="number" it works perfect. But I don't know why.

Comment: I tested in Firefox and I got a correct result, with little changes: https://jsfiddle.net/fhx7eq4L/